# Firebase Database Rules indexOn FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

First, I got this warning

> FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "id" at /data/places/tr to your security rules for better performance

After I changed firebase rules.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true",
   "data": {
    "places": {
      "tr": {
        ".indexOn": "id"
      }
    }
   }
  }
}
```

Now I don't have a warning, but code is not working.

Comment: Describe "not working".  Any error messages?

Comment: no error message on terminal .the webpage is not working .example localhost:3000/id this url not open.